# Create user roles and permissions extending the existing User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I want to create user roles (member, partner, admin, etc) [extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #custom fields
```

What is the best way to create and assign the permissions in this case?

I see many ways to do it:

1. [Programmatically creating permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions):

   ```
   permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_publish',
                                          name='Can Publish Posts',
                                          content_type=content_type)
   ```
2. [Included in a model object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions):

   ```
   class Task(models.Model):
       ...
       class Meta:
           permissions = (
               ("view_task", "Can see available tasks"),
               ("change_task_status", "Can change the status of tasks"),
               ("close_task", "Can remove a task by setting its status as closed"),
       )
   ```

   is it harcoded? But I want to include the permissions in the `Member class`, I don't know if it's a good way to do it.

How can I add the `Member class` to `member group`? Or do I have to add permissions to `member group`?:

```
view_task = Permission.objects.get(name='view_task')
membergroup.permissions.add(view_task)
```

and after that add user by user from `Member class` to `member group`?:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='test')
membergroup = Group.objects.get(name='member')
user.groups.add(membergroup)
```

So, I want to put the permissions in `Member class` and put the class in a `member group`. I don't know if it's ok.

I want to know if a user is in a `member group` for example. I see a way but I'm not sure if it is good. Because I have to retrive all user from the group each time:

```
users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name="member").user_set.all()
if user in users_in_group:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert with permissions in Django, but as far as I know, the main tasks to do (not especially in this order, you do what you need when you need it) are the following:

- You create permissions
- You create groups
- You link users to your groups
- You link permissions to your groups

Using this "pattern" allows you to be flexible giving users the ability to be in 0->N groups and the groups being linked to 0->N permissions.

This part of the doc explains how to use permissions with examples :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

That being said, be careful to not mix model extension with permissions:

- You extends User model when you want to add special attributes on it. For example, ClientUser and BusinessSeller could be User model extensions because you do want to have different attributes on them. This is not related to permissions.
  This means you can use permissions on users without extending the User model.

Not sure this answers totally your question, but I hope it makes things clearer to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're right, it's more flexible like this. I don't know where to put the code. is it a kind of boostrap and for each request it creates everything?

Comment: I think I can `create permissions`, `create groups` and `link permissions to groups` just one time. The other thing is I'm going to link user to groups dynamically because it depends of user subscription or if the user change the role. So, I think it will be at the end, isn't?

Comment: The tasks I listed are not to follow in this particular order :) I guess [this part of the Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization) will help you with examples of how to create permissions. You can create/edit/delete permissions/user/groups when you want, you're free.

Comment: So what would you propose if I wanted to extend users in a way that would affect the things that they'd be able to see. For example, have them belong to a company and display only Company relevant information to them

Comment: @RohanNahata I think you should not extend User model for that purpose, unless you have a good reason to. As it is stated, it sounds like you need a permission (or nothing).